# Compare keys and values from 2 arrays and store same values

Tags: php

I want to compare keys from one array against values from another array, and when a match is made to store the value from the first array (whose key matched the value in the second one).

With my code, it always echoes out `4`. How can I modify it so that it echoes out `1 2 3 4`?

The code:

```
$first = array('location', 'genre', 'studio', 'Lord_Of_the_Rings');
$second = array(
    'location' => 1, 
    'genre' => 2, 
    'studio' => 3, 
    'Lord_Of_the_Rings' => 4
);


while ($el = current($second)) {
    $d .=  ','.key($second);
    next($second);
}
$d = ltrim($d, ',');
$d = explode(',', $d);

foreach ($first as $the_tax) {

    foreach ($d as $key => $v) {
        if (in_array($v, $first)) {
            $t = $second[$v];
        }
    }

    echo $t.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Your code seems very complicated. Or maybe your sample data is oversimplified. For example, why do you need two arrays when `array_keys( $second ) == $first` and `array_values( $second ) == range( 1, 4 )`? BTW, `array_flip` could be useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honsest, if you wouldn't explain your goal, I wouldn't even understand what you're trying to do by your code. Try like this:

```
<?php
$first = array('location', 'genre', 'studio', 'Lord_Of_the_Rings');
$second = array(
    'location' => 1, 
    'genre' => 2, 
    'studio' => 3, 
    'Lord_Of_the_Rings' => 4
);

$intersect = array_intersect($first, array_keys($second));
foreach($intersect as $key)
    echo $second[$key];

?>
```

Comment: I said what I wanted to achieve in the first sentence. To elaborate, I am making input boxes and wanted each to have the value of the second array. this answer actually does what I asked, but unfortunately it is not working inside my code as expected. I might have to reformulate the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should move/add add an `echo` statement into the block where you assign the value of `$t`, maybe this way:

```
foreach ($first as $the_tax) {

    foreach ($d as $key => $v) {
        if (in_array($v, $first)) {
            $t = $second[$v];
            echo $t.' ';
        }
    }

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can flip the keys in second array, and then take the intersection of the 2. something along these lines

```
<?php
$first = array('location', 'genre', 'studio', 'Lord_Of_the_Rings');
$second = array(
    'location' => 1, 
    'genre' => 2, 
    'studio' => 3, 
    'Lord_Of_the_Rings' => 4
  );
$flipped = array_flip($second); 
print implode(' ',array_keys(array_intersect($flipped, $first)));
?>
```